# Select first element of each node via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML document like this

```
<Persons>
  <Company>
    ...
    <Employee>
        <name>1</name>
        <name>2</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>3</name>
        <name>4</name>
    </Employee>
  </Company>
  <Company>
    ...
    <Employee>
        <name>5</name>
        <name>6</name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>7</name>
        <name>8</name>
    </Employee>
  </Company>
</Persons>
```

And I want to catch first element of each node.  Here, **I want to get 1 and 5**.

I am using this XPath to do this:

```
/Persons/Company//name[1]/text()
```

**But I am getting 1,3,5,7**

Note: I cannot use `/Persons/Company/Employee[1]//name[1]/text()`
because `Employee` is an arbitrary tag and I don't know where actually the `name` element resides inside the `Company` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath

```
/Persons/Company//*[1]//name[1]/text()
```

Will select

```
1
5
```

as requested without specifying `Employee` explicitly.

**Note**: You may be able to tighten up one or both of the `//` specifiers to `/`, depending upon unstated specifics of your general case.  (Use `/` when testing for a direct parent-child relationship rather than a more general self-descendant relationship.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for the `descendant::` axis:

```
/Persons/Company/descendant::name[1]
```

This is a good example of a case where `//` and `descendant::` mean slightly different things - the definition of `//` is that it is a shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` including the slashes, so

```
/Persons/Company//name[1]
```

means

```
/Persons/Company/descendant-or-self::node()/name[1]
```

This makes it clear that the `[1]` applies only to the final child step (so returning every `name` that is the first `name` in its respective parent), not to the whole search for descendants.